# Firebase firestore query by datetime show different results depending of the timezone of the phone Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, datetime, timezone

I am having a problem with timezone when saving and querying bettwing dates on firebase firestore. I wanna save the dates without matter about the timezone just like (2022-12-31 00:00:00.000), but when i do this on the client side depending of the timezone it saves on a different day, and query result different data too.

How do i do this independent of the timezone? i mean if the user is on UTC+4 or UTC-4 it does not change the day or hour when saving, just save (2022-12-31 00:00:00.000) on the firestore database?
Somehow i do not understand it is querying and saving based on the local timezone i guess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe what you need is to rely on Firebase's `Timestamp`, not the local dates from your client

Comment: @Gwhyyy, sorry but i did not understand what you mean. To query the or save the values i need to use the date of the user on local phone or there's another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [Firebase's TimeStamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) while adding data to the `firebase`

> **A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar**, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time. It is encoded using the Proleptic Gregorian Calendar which extends the Gregorian calendar backwards to year one. It is encoded assuming all minutes are 60 seconds long, i.e. leap seconds are "smeared" so that no leap second table is needed for interpretation.

#### To access timeStamp use [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html)

##### Usage

###### Add data

```
_firestore
.collection('post')
.add({
   'text': postText,
   'created': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()  //  This timestamp is independent of the timezone
});
```

###### Query data

```
_firestore.
.collection('post')
.orderBy('created', descending: false)    //  Data will be same irrespective of access point
.snapshots()
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much @Krishna Acharya, another question, this FieldValue.serverTimestamt() gets the actual date from the server right, but if i wanna get the user imput and convert to a timestamp, how do you could do it?

Comment: The whole purpose will be defeated if you do so ! User lives in different region and time differs and then you see inconsistent data which you demand to avoid

Comment: Humm, i see. I will have to think more about this, i want the user to save the day only independent of the time. For example, if the user select 28/01/2023, i want to query anywhere and return the values on that day independent of the time. Thank you so much.

Comment: This works absolutely the way you said. Irrespective of the time frame you live in, this store according to the `GMT` time standards, so that the date is stored same throughout the globe